# Issue with displaying Euros using .ToString() Method C#

Tags: c#, winforms, math, tostring, euro

I am still learning the basics with C# and i am completely baffled by this issue. I am making a program in C# using Windows Forms to convert USD to EURO and vice versa. I am rounding both outputs to the 2nd decimal using the Math.Round method. The issue i am having is when i convert the output to a string using the ".ToString()" method using the "\u20AC" function, it only displays the EURO symbol and not the amount. But when i take out the "\u20AC" function, it displays the amount and not the EURO symbol. Now the really interesting part is, when i use the exact same line of code when i convert EURO to USD, the output comes out perfectly fine with the dollar sign and the amount. Am i doing something wrong here? Here is my Code:

```
    private void btnEXC1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double USD = Convert.ToDouble(tbUSD.Text);
        double EURO;

        EURO = USD * 1.18113;
        lblUSDTOEURO.Text = Math.Round(EURO,2).ToString("\u20AC");


    }

    private void btnEXC2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double EURO = Convert.ToDouble(tbEURO.Text);
        double USD;

        USD = EURO * 0.846648;
        lblEUROTOUSD.Text = Math.Round(USD, 2).ToString("c");
    }
```

Comment: Read the documentation on how to format currencies for different locales: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Use this format string for euros: `"\u20AC0.00"`. In this mask the `0.00` part represents the display format for a number.

Comment: link64 Im not sure you read the title of my question. I am having an issue displaying the output correctly when the code is perfectly fine.
Thank you Dmitry, that worked perfectly, i wish my professor wouldve stated to do that other than just the "\u20AC". You wouldnt happen to know why it had to be added?

Comment: See my answer below. You can mark it as accepted if it is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this format string for euros: `"\u20AC0.00"`.
In this mask the `0.00` part represents the display format for a number.

In your mask there is no display format for a number, therefore it displays as the only char.
The `"c"` format string is a predefined format that is intended for currency values: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).